# How to call mainform method in another form in usercontrol C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with WinForms in C#. I am trying to call MainForm method in one of the form in user control.
I have MainForm like this:

```
namespace Project
{
  public partial class MainForm : Form
   {
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
    
    public void TempCommand()
      {
       StartTemp();
      }
   }
 }
```

I have the button click in the user control. When I click that button then it will open another form. I have the code like this in the user control.

```
   private TempCalib _tempCalib = new TempCalib();

   private void calibBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tempCalib.Show();
    }
```

It will open another from and I have one button in that from. I need to call MainForm method when I click "Ok" button in this form.

```
namespace Project
{
public partial class TempCalib : Form
{
 
    public TempCalib()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // I need to call the mainfrom "TempCommand" method here.
        this.Hide();
    }


   }
 }
```

Can anyone help me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a really bad design, and there are better ways to do it. Move that method out of the MainForm class **NOW.**

Comment: You could use a custom event that is declared in your UserControl. Then your form needs to handle this event and call the method you want to call. If you let the UserControl access your form, you are hard-linking both with each other which decreases reusability of your UserControl.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. I'd like to learn more about better ways to do this. Can you share a link or some key words?

Answer (score 4):

### Quick answer

Just add a reference to the primary form in your secondary form:

```
public partial class TempCalib : Form
{
    private  MainForm _main

    public TempCalib(MainForm main) : this()
    {
        _main = main;
    }

    /// Other stuffs
}
```

Then assign value when you construct your secondary form:

```
private TempCalib _tempCalib;
private void calibBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (_tempCalib == null)
         _tempCalib = new TempCalib(this);

     _tempCalib.Show();
}
```

If `calibBtn_Click` isn't inside `MainForm` (but it's inside a `UserControl` on it) then you can replace `_tempCalib` initialization with:

```
_tempCalib = new TempCalib((MainWindow)FindForm());
```

You'll be then able to call the primary form:

```
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _main.TempCommand();  
    this.Hide();
}
```

Notes: this is just one option, you may create a property to hold `MainForm` reference (so secondary form can be reused and it'll be more designer friendly) moreover `TempCalib` is not an `UserControl` but a `Form` (pretty raw but for an `UserControl` you may just check its parent Form and cast it to proper type).

### Improvements

Such kind of references are often an alert. Usually UI components shouldn't not be so coupled and a public `Form`'s method to perform something very often is the signal that you have too much logic in your `Form`. How to improve this?

**1. DECOUPLE CONTROLS**. Well a first step may be to decouple them a little bit, just add an event in `TempCalib` and make `MainForm` its receiver:

```
public partial class TempCalib : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingMustBeDone;

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSomethingMustBeDone(EventArgs.Empty); / TO DO
       this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Then in `MainForm`:

```
private TempCalib _tempCalib;
private void calibBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (_tempCalib == null)
     {
         _tempCalib = new TempCalib();
         _tempCalib.SomethingMustBeDone += _tempCalib_SomethingMustBeDone;

         // In _tempCalib_SomethingMustBeDone you'll invoke proper member
         // and possibly hide _tempCalib (remove it from OkButton_Click)
     }

     _tempCalib.Show();
}
```

**2. DECOUPLE LOGIC FROM CONTROLS**. UI changes pretty often, logic not (and when it changes probably isn't in parallel with UI). This is just the first step (now `TempCalib` isn't aware of who will use it). Next step (to be performed when too much things happen inside your form) is to remove this kind of logic from the form itself. Little example (very raw), keep `TempCalib` as before (with the event) and change `MainForm` to be *passive*:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler Calibrate;

    protected virtual void OnCalibrate(EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Now let's create a class to control the flow and logic:

```
public class MyTaskController
{
    private MainForm _main;
    private TempCalib _tempCalib;

    public void Start()
    {
        _main = new MainForm();
        _main.Calibrate += OnCalibrationRequested;
        _main.Show(); // Or whatever else
    }

    private void OnCalibrationRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tempCalib == null)
        {
            _tempCalib = new TempCalib();
            _tempCalib.SomethingMustBeDone += OnSomethingMustBeDone();
        }

        _tempCalib.Show();
    }

    private OnSomethingMustBeDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform the task here then hide calibration window
        _tempCalib.Hide();
    }    
}
```

Yes, you'll need to write much more code but this will **decouple logic** (what to do as response to an action, for example) from UI itself. When program grows up this will help you to change UI as needed keeping logic unaware of that (and in one well defined place). I don't even mention that this will allow you to use **different resources** (people) to write logic and UI (or to **reuse** logic for different UI, WinForms and WPF, for example). Anyway IMO the most obvious and well repaid benefit is...**readability**: you'll always know where logic is and where UI management is, no search, no confusion, no mistakes.

**3. DECOUPLE LOGIC FROM IMPLEMENTATION**. Again you have more steps to perform (when needed). Your *controller* is still aware of concrete types (`MainForm` and `TempCalib`). In case you need to select a different form at run-time (for example to have a complex interface and a simplified one or to use dependency injection) then you have to decouple controller using interfaces. Just an example:

```
public interface IUiWindow
{
    void Show();
    void Hide();
}

public interface IMainWindow : IUiWindow
{
    event EventHandler Calibrate;
}

public interface ICalibrationWindow : IUiWindow
{
    event EventHandler SomethingMustBeDone;
}
```

Comment: @reddy It means that `this` is not of type `MainForm`. Do it inside `MainForm` code (or get a reference to it inside your UserControl, for example using `(MainForm)FindForm()` instead of `this`).

Comment: I am sorry for asking once again, CalibBtn_Click is in usercontrol not in mainfrom. I tried your modified suggestion. But what is this (MainWindow)FindForm()); because i am getting error in both words like "Missing directory or reference for "MainWindow". do i need any reference or directive. even "FindForm" does not exist. do i need to add any reference?

Comment: @reddy FindForm() comes from the Control class (so it's there, in WinForms) for every (non static) method. MainWindow should be your main form name (at least from you example). Change it according to your real code (or use ParentForm property). Do it step by step with dummy variables, you'll get it...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions and clear explanations about concept. I have problem with FindForm(); i can find it and i will solve it.Thanks alot for showing me the way.

Comment: @reddy you welcome, you can even use ParentForm property (roughly equivalent to (Form)TopLevelControl). By the way...I would suggest to go directly to _improvement no. 1_...

Comment: then I have to change implementation.1 because i have CalibBtn_Click in user control not in the main from. So can use same type of event even in usercontrol.

Comment: @reddy yes from design perspective it's much much better (if you can't...use _improvement #2_, it's little bit more complicated but you'll keep controls unaware of each other). Try to read [this little tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp). Trust me...what you pay now in complexity will be repaid 100X when your program will grow...over 1000 lines of code)

Comment: Thanks for your support and help. I am going through provided tutorial. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You create an event in your usercontrol and subscribe to this in the mainform.
That is the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom event that is declared in your `UserControl`. Then your form needs to handle this event and call the method you want to call. If you let the `UserControl` access your form, you are hard-linking both with each other which decreases reusability of your `UserControl`.

For example, in `TempCalib`:

```
public delegate void OkClickedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event OkClickedHandler OkClicked;

private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure someone is listening to event
    if (OkClicked == null) return;

    OkClicked(sender, e);

    this.Hide();       
}
```

in your mainform:

```
private void Mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tempCalib.OkClicked += CalibOkClicked;
}

private void CalibOkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartTemp();
}
```

Comment: I have tried as your suggestion but "if (OkClicked == null)" this always null so it is returning always. What should be the problem why it is always equal to null when i click ok button..

Comment: @reddy: It is null if nobody listens to this event, but above i have shown how you register the event handler in `MainForm_Load`: `_tempCalib.OkClicked += CalibOkClicked;`.

Comment: I have done the same thing in mainform. I have registered event handler in mainfrom_load as like you shown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Form1 Code:

```
    UserControl1 myusercontrol = new UserControl1();

    public void TabClose(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        i = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myusercontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage();
        myTabPage.Text = "Student";
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(myusercontrol);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        myusercontrol.OkClick += TabClose;

    }
```

UserControl1 Code:

```
     public delegate void OkClickedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public event OkClickedHandler OkClick;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OkClick == null) return;
        OkClick(sender, e);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

From user control try this:

```
MainForm form = this.TopLevelControl as MainForm;
form.TempCommand();
```