# Accessing main form objects in other .cs files

Tags: c#, object

It's easy to access sub-window's objects from main file because we must create the sub window anyway. So there's something like this:

```
SubForm subform = new SubForm();
if (subform.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    text = subform.textBox1.Text; 
    //...
}
```

But I have some troubles with editing a combobox (placed inside main form) by a sub-cs file. I can't simply create a new main window. I've edited Program.cs file:

```
static class Program
    {
        public static MainForm mainform; //main window reference
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(mainform = new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

Now I can access the combobox:

```
Program.mainform.comboCurves.Items.Add("test");
```

Is it any better solution for this?

Comment: Sure: insert one (or more) appropriate abstraction layer between the combo and the code that wants to influence it. This is really too open-ended to give concrete suggestions.

Comment: Normally this is a question for the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ But creating static variables of forms isn't a great pattern. Why should the 'sub-cs' file create combobox items?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call mainform method in another form in usercontrol C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672276/how-to-call-mainform-method-in-another-form-in-usercontrol-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also pass a reference to your mainform directly into your subform, at least your main form won't be available to your whole application :

MainWindow.cs :

```
SubForm subform = new SubForm(this);
```

SubForm.cs :

```
public partial class SubForm : Form
{
    private MainForm mainForm;
    public SubForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }
}
```

So now you can access it like mainForm.comboCurves.Items.Add("test");

---

Also, a better way would be to have your main form inherit form an interface that exposes only the necessary stuff :

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IRestrictedInterfaceOfMainForm
{
    public void AddStuff(string stuff)
    {
        comboCurves.Items.Add(stuff);
    }
}

public interface IRestrictedInterfaceOfMainForm
{
    void AddStuff();
}

public partial class SubForm : Form
{
    private IRestrictedInterfaceOfMainFormmainForm mainForm;
    public SubForm(IRestrictedInterfaceOfMainFormmainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }
}
```

That way you only access what you really need and don't play directly with MainForm's controls. For example, if you want to change comboCurves to an array of textboxes, the second form won't even notice it.

---

Your solution works, but you should always try to expose the least amount of information, which is partly covered by the [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), from the SOLID principles.

Comment: I think the second example is more elegant, this will allow the passed object to be of any type (at least IRestrictedInterfaceOfMainForm), instead of a MainForm.

Comment: I like the first option, it's easier for me (don't know interfaces yet). I have just tested it and I'm satisfied. Thanks!