# Form sending data to another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class

I'm currently trying to make a form that sends 2 class, then receives the data, uses them but want to shoot them back to the original form. Any idea on how I could?

This is when i call my second form:

```
        var tmp = new Pjeu(P1,P2);
        tmp.Show();
```

P are Players. Here's the class:
//---

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name;
    public int pts1;
    public int pts2;
    public int num;
};
```

And I receive the data like this:

```
label3.Text = P1.Name;
label5.Text=P2.Name;
```

I want to use `P1.pts` or shoot back a number to it. Is it possible the way I do?

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007088/change-label-text-via-listview-itemactivate/41008137?noredirect=1#comment69225672_41008137

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007088/change-label-text-via-listview-itemactivate/41008137?noredirect=1#comment69225672_41008137

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi way:

```
public class Player
{
    public void Pa(string p1,string p2)
    {
        p1 = Name;
        p2 = Name;
    }
    public string pass1(int ps1)
    {
        return ps1.ToString();
    }
    public string pass2(int ps2)
    {
        return ps2.ToString();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int pts1 { get; set; }
    public int pts2 { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

and call:

```
        Player p = new Player();
        p.Pa(Label1.Text, Label2.Text);
        Label1.Text = p.pts1.ToString();
        Label2.Text = p.pts2.ToString();
```